# Regex: matching string with 2 specific characters

Tags: regex

I'm working in Google Analytics and trying to use the RegEx advanced filter option to display page names that contain two `/`, but not three `/`. The text string within the first section will always be `products`; however, after the second `/` it is random.

For example, 
I want to include these page name strings:

```
 /products/skis
 /products/snowboards
 /products/skates
```

I want to exclude these page name strings:

```
 /products/skis/mens
 /products/snowboards/womens
 /products/skates/red
```

Again, the `products` part is consistent...but the second text section is random.

Appreciate any help -- thanks!

Comment: Have you  made any effort to solve this problem yourself? We're not a code (or regex) writing service; we expect you to have made an effort to do something yourself first before posting here. If you've done so, please [edit] your question and include the latest of those efforts. If you've not, please do so now.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be this::

```
^\/products\/[a-zA-Z]+$
```

This would capture the first slash, followed by 'products', followed by a second slash, and then any text string (without special characters). Nothing else would come after.

Answer (score 0):

To match pages names starting by `/products/` and not containing a third slash, you can use this regex:

```
^\/products\/[^\/]+$
```